# Rejoining a default media receiver session, can't control media

Tags: google-cast

I'm working with the default media receiver in a chrome sender clientside webapp. I can successfully connect to my chromecast and play an mp3 file and pause/stop/play it.

When I refresh the page, my sessionListener callback sees the active media. I verified that the sessionId is the same, but when I call .pause() or .play() on the existing session, it does not effect the chromecast.

I'm using the Beta Cast extension. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try CastVideos-chrome and see if that works fine for you?

Answer (score 0):

I was mistakenly calling .play(), .pause(), etc on the top level session and not session.media[0]